# Query show Retail Item with Itemset in Ms Sql

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a task to show the query result like below:

Table 1 item show one time and Table 2 table have related record than show that details.

Kindly look below example

Table 1:

```
ItemNumber   Retail_Price  IsItemSet
5000           10000           Y
5001            5000           N
```

Table 2:

```
ItemNumber   item_DetailsNo  Retail_Price  
5000           10              2000
5000           11              8000
```

I want result like below:

```
ItemNumber   Retail_Price  
5000           10000
5000            8000
5000            2000
5001            5000
```

Result in a single query.

Comment: Why have you 3 tagged versions of SQL Server, 2 of which are **completely** unsupported? (I have removed these, as the 3 versions are all significantly different.) What have you tried so far, why didn't it work? What is your question, all you tell us if that ***you*** have been tasked to do this; you don't need to tell us what you've been asked to do, SO is a Q&A website not a blogging site.

Comment: This sounds like UNION

Answer (score 1):

use **UNION**

```
select ItemNumber,Retail_Price from  table1
union 
Select ItemNumber,Retail_Price from  table2
order by ItemNumber,Retail_Price desc
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***Try this -***

```
select ItemNumber, Retail_Price  
From Table1
Union All
select ItemNumber, Retail_Price  
From Table2 
Order by ItemNumber, Retail_Price  Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table  #Table1 (ItemNumber int,   Retail_Price int,  IsItemSet varchar(4))
insert into #Table1 values
(5000,10000,'Y'),(5001, 5000,'N') 

create table  #Table2 (ItemNumber int,   item_DetailsNo int,  Retail_Price int)
insert into #Table2 values
(5000,10,2000),(5000,11,8000)

select ItemNumber,  Retail_Price from #Table1
UNION
select  ItemNumber,Retail_Price from #Table2



drop table #Table1
drop table #Table2
```

OUTPUT

```
ItemNumber  Retail_Price
5000       2000
5000       8000
5000       10000
5001       5000
```